# Stream from BundleResource

Tags: c#, nsimage, nsbundle, monomac

I have a MonoMac project and I need a `Stream` reference to an item I have set as a `BundleResource` (an image).

I have an image in my project whose build action I've set to `BundleResource` (I'm assuming this is the Visual Studio equivalent of setting an item's build action to `Resource`. Now, in my code, I want to open a stream to this resource so that my application can use it. In WPF this would be done by:

```
Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);
```

However, I cannot find any documentation on MonoMac on what the equivalent would be. If I even find a way to get the data for file, that should be okay as I would just wrap that in a `MemoryStream` and then some point down the line hope that `NSImage.FromStream()` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource` method to get the path to the resource. You can access the resource using that path.

Comment: Isn't the path going to be from within the bundle, though? Will the standard `FileStream` constructor work for that?

Comment: @sohum: The bundle is an ordinary folder on the disk so it should work fine.